# AWS Load Balancer is returning NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

I have a CNAME record pointing from the subdomain I bought `sub.example.com` to my load balancer `example.region.elb.amazonaws.com`. When I visit `https://sub.example.com` the website works fine but when I visit the load balancer it's telling me that the certificate is invalid.

I know this has been asked a few times, but the difference is that my setup works on the domain I bought not on the load balancer itself. So how do I make the certificate valid on ACM? Or is it fine to leave it as is, since `https` works fine on `sub.example.com`? I'm using cloudflare DNS and cloudflare's origin certificate if that matters.

Comment: It depends on the reason it says its not valid. Note that the root domain eg `foo.com` should not be a CNAME.

Comment: I'm using a subdomain for the CNAME, will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have SSL certificate for `elb.amazonaws.com`, because this is not your domain, but it belongs to AWS. To get a valid SSL cert you need to have **your own domain**. You can buy it using Route53 or any other domain registrar.

Comment: I've already bought the domain. So from what I understand, the SSL certificate will always bn "invalid" for the alb. does this mean my setup is already correct?

Comment: @EvaineLeBlanc Yes. You can only use you domain, not the elb default domain for proper https. You can setup redirection rule from alb domain to your domain.